# Apex Custom Rest service - Whats the avaliable Heap Size?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I have written an apex custom rest service in salesforce which sends lot of data.

When i run some code in it and check available heap size using below syntax i get 6 MB? Is apex heap size not 12 MB for async transactions. This custom rest service is exposed to end system who do inbound calls to salesforce.

```
Limits.getLimitHeapSize()

 <avaliableheap>6000000</avaliableheap>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Apex Custom REST Service is not an asynchronous transaction. The client invokes it via a REST call and gets a response back.

If you need 12 MB Heap, you need to delegate work to a queueable (or batchable or future). Of course, such delegated worker can't reply back to the original REST message

Comment: ah crap. I wanted that 12 MB heap badly! so many limits